# I am not getting the minor radius for even after scrolling down.

Tags: mesh

[image: this is what i am getting]

when i am selecting torus this(image attached) is what i am getting and there is no option of changing minor radius.

Comment: What you want to change is only available just after the object is created. After that this is considered as a simple mesh with no particular property (like torus properties).

Comment: Once you've created an object and done any kind of transformation (rotate, scale, move) or selected a different object, there is no way to bring the original creation parameters back. You can eithre edit the current object with other tools, or create a new one and set new parameters.

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org